# Raspberry Pi: ssh connection refused

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, connection-refused

I have a problem with a raspberry pi.
This morning I switched on the raspi and the ssh does not work. If I try to connect typing

```
ssh -vvv pi@192.168.1.33
```

the output is this:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.33 [192.168.1.33] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.33 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.33 port 22: Connection refused
```

I want to underline that I have not edited any config file or similar from yesterday, when everything worked well.

I don't know if this can be useful but I opened the file var/log/auth.log on the raspi but there is no line about today. Just lines about yesterday. Probably ssh process does not start?

Comment: There is a special Stack Exchange site for Raspberry Pi. I guess you can get more help there.

Comment: Are you able to connect a monitor and keyboard? If you can, what output do you get if you execute `sudo netstat -tlpn`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just forgot to connect my Pi and my laptop to the same router. My laptop was connected to my domestic wifi and my raspberry to another wifi source. So my answer is, try to connect both through the same local network and retry the ssh process.

If you want to connect through the world wide web, buy a domain. It gives an address to your Pi.

Else, there are several other answers on Stackoverflow.